# github workflow test insists on python 3.8?

Tags: github, workflow

We have push & test workflows which from which we attempt to drop python 3.7, 3.8 and add python 3.10, 3.11. This works, except for some reason the test workflow wants to test the 3 os's with python 3.8 as well, even though there is no longer any mention of 3.8 in the yml files?

See https://github.com/oscal-compass/compliance-trestle/pull/1512.